# redirect_to :back, while still maintaining inputs on form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am rendering a `new answer` form from the `questions` show template as follow:

```
= render 'answers/form'
```

Where `answers/form` is as follow:

```
= form_for Answer.new do |f|
  .field
    = hidden_field(:answer, :question_id, value: params["id"])
  .field
    %br/
    = f.text_area :content, required: true, class: "form-control"
  .actions
    %div
      = button_tag type: "submit", class: "button-hollow-b" do
        %i.fa.fa-stethoscope
          Post Help
```

My question now is this:

If error occurs in saving answer, maybe due to validation or anything, how do I make this controller `create` method redirect back to the question show page, with the filled in answer still on the form, and the errors that prevented saving as well, just like using `render`?

```
def create
    @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

`render :new` renders the new answer template, but not on the questions' `show` page.

`redirect_to :back` on the other hand clears my filled in answer, and does not show the errors on the form.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `render 'questions/show'`?

Comment: thanks @Pavan but this does not work at all. the show page is specific to a question, I will include question_id, but even then, `redirect_to` clears the inputs from my form.

Comment: `redirect_to` results in another http request. It will clear filled data and validation errors. You will have to use `render`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to render `questions/show`. Your problem is actually in how you create the answers. For this to work, you'll need a nested form.

Follow this guide from the rails casts:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast

If that link doesn't align with your plan,then you need an actual object that you can reference. Here you're using `Answer.new`, which means that every time that form is created a new object is created. You'll want to use `@answer = @question.answers.build` in the controller and then use `@answer` instead of `Answer.new` That way your `@answer.errors` will work.